# Buffing Unarmed Attacks

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monk, unarmed-combat

In D&D 5e after the errata it was clarified that monks unarmed attacks are not weapons.
But in saying that, they are melee weapon attacks which is a form of a weapon attack.

My question is for spells like Divine Favor or Ensnaring strike that specifically state "your weapon attacks" or "hit a creature with a weapon attack" do they work and buff your unarmed attack?

I know a buff spell such as Magic Weapon won't work as you specifically improve the stats of a "non-magical weapon".

There's just no clarification for whether or not these spells definitively work that I could find.

Comment: "But in saying that, they are melee weapon attacks which is a form of a weapon attack." Can you cite the source for this? I'm confused by the statement that unarmed strikes aren't weapons but they are weapon attacks.

Comment: @MarkWells see the duplicate link above. tl;dr it is from the PHB errata.